# Google Sign-in Javascript with redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, oauth-2.0, google-api

Hello guys i am working on a web application and im in the part of authenticating my user.

Im sorry if there is already an awsner but i couldn't find it...

I have this sample code that works but gives me a popup (what i want is redirect):

```
var googleUser = {};

gapi.load('auth2', function () {
    // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
    auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'my_client_id',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        //ux_mode: 'redirect' //tried with redirect but i don't get user on object on click handler
    });

    auth2.attachClickHandler(document.getElementById('loginG'), {},
    function (googleUser) {

        var usermail = googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail();
        var username = googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
        var userimage = googleUser.getBasicProfile().getImageUrl();

        console.log(googleUser);

    });
});
```

So with this code i can get the user information/token and login into the app, but this happens with a popup and i want to do it with redirect like it's done on this website: https://www.realfevr.com/en/home-page/

I tried doing it with ux_mode: redirect and it does in-fact redirect the login but I can't get the object of the user so i must be doing something wrong here...

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong to not get the user from the redirect ?

Comment: When you tried the `ux_mode: 'redirect'`, did you specify `redirect_uri` value as well? It becomes required.

Comment: I didn't so I should use redirect to a different page to check if user is logged in ?

Comment: In OAuth2, the redirectUri is a URL that the user will be redirected to after authentication. The URI handler should parse the URI and extract tokens from it.

Comment: After parsing the URI and extracting the token what should I do to get the user that authenticated ? Is there any method on gapi that i should pass the token and get user object ? Thanks for explaning me

Comment: That is what you are looking for https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with you. When using popup, everything works fine. When useing redirect, the only thing I can get is the id_token in the url parameter which lacks the name of the user.